# Storing Large file in Dictionary (or SQLite)

Tags: c#, sqlite, file-io, dictionary

I am writing a C# console app which reads files on disk and make a key value pair out of it.

There are several thousand files and anticipating problems, I used SQLite to save this into a table.
I landed up in problems immediately as SQLite file now goes beyond 1.6GB and on 32bit environment, my program goes out of memory.

There is no other way than reading the files once and storing it into an dictionary (or similar), so that the key can be used to query for value.

I am using Framework 4.0.

Is there any solution for this kind of problem? Unfortunately, I cannot change the way the program is written.

I searched here on Stackoverflow and could not conclude what is best option forwards,

Comment: Have you looked at [RaptorDB](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/190504/RaptorDB)? I think that would address your problem.

Comment: Eventually you can write the data in a zip file instead of in a directory, this should decrease the size.

Comment: Let me check for RaptorRB

Comment: Why is there "no other way than reading the files once and storing it into an dictionary"? You're already "reading the files" so why not leave them on disk, save a path to the disk file in the database, then read the files from disk only when needed? There's something important you're not telling us.

Comment: There are several hundred files with key value pair information. The key is queried after reading another XML files which are also large in number. Unfortunately, there is no way to link the XML with the file in which the key (or value) will exist. Hence I need a repository to search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your replies.
I was able to accomplish the task using SQLite.

I could not use PersistentDictionary.

Comment: How did you achieve this?

Comment: I had to go with 64 bit Windows.

Answer (score 0):

[PersistentDictionary](http://managedesent.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PersistentDictionaryDocumentation) ought to do just what you need.